# How do I fill drilled holes on a concrete floor and won't make it look fresh and blend it with existing floor?

Tags: repair, flooring

I want to try hiding a drilled hole as much as possible on a concrete floor. I will fill the holes, but it's obviously visible. I don't want it to look fresh. Is there anything I should do before hand that’ll help blend it in afterwards? Then afterwards when I’m done is there anything anyone recommends for making it blend in and not look like freshly poured concrete in the holes?

Someone would help me out on this but he doesn’t have any ideas for hiding it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using epoxy or a urethane based putty to fill the holes, scrape some of the nearby cement with sandpaper or a wire brush and brush that over the filler while it's still "tacky". It should help to hide it a little.